# Unnest json to multiple rows splitted into key and value columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to unnest the column `json_blob`:
`SELECT '{"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}' AS json_blob`
to look like this at the end:

```
key | val
----------
"a" | [1,2,3]
"b" | [4, 5, 6]
```

Note that different rows can have different keys and it's a lot of them. I don't want to write all of them by hand.

Answer (score -1):

The schema of the JSON would have to stay the same, then you could do this:

```sql
with t as (SELECT '{"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}' AS json_blob)

select key, val
from t cross join unnest([
  struct('a' as key, json_extract(json_blob, '$.a') as val), 
  struct('b' as key, json_extract(json_blob, '$.b') as val)
])
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention some important facts. They are added now.

Comment: since json_extract only works with scalars ... I don't think there's a good solution. Maybe something around regexp_extract(), but this also depends heavily on stable patterns in your json string

Answer (score -1):

Below example can be a good starting point - but really depends on pattern of your json

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '{"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}' AS json_blob UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"a": [11, 12, 13], "c": [14, 15, 16]}' UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"d": 21, "b": [24, 25, 26]}' 
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(kv, ': ')[OFFSET(0)] AS key,
  SPLIT(kv, ': ')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(json_blob, r'("\w+":[^"]*)(?:,|})')) kv
```

with result

```
Row key value    
1   "a" [1, 2, 3]    
2   "b" [4, 5, 6]    
3   "a" [11, 12, 13]     
4   "c" [14, 15, 16]     
5   "d" 21   
6   "b" [24, 25, 26]
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll get a basic (careful about robustness against nulls) but proper implementation using this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  jsonObjectKeysValues(input STRING)
  RETURNS STRUCT<product_type ARRAY<STRING>,
  product_versions ARRAY<STRING>>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    this.product_type = Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
    this.product_versions = Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
    return this;
""";
WITH
  SOURCE AS (
  SELECT
    '{"fruits":["apples","oranges","grapes"], "vegetables":["leek","cabbage","zucchini"]}' AS json),
  parsed AS (
  SELECT
    jsonObjectKeysValues(json).*
  FROM
    SOURCE)
SELECT
  unnested_entries.product_type,
  unnested_entries.product_versions
FROM
  parsed,
  UNNEST(ARRAY(
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT product_type, product_versions
    FROM
      UNNEST(product_type) product_type
    WITH
    OFFSET
    JOIN
      UNNEST(product_versions) product_versions
    WITH
    OFFSET
    USING
      (
      OFFSET
        ) ) ) unnested_entries
```

Result is

| Row | product_type | product_versions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fruits | apples,oranges,grapes |
| 2 | vegetables | leek,cabbage,zucchini |